# Cows milk protein transferability through breast milk

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-biology, proteins, microbiology

I understand that cow's milk protein(casein) transfers through breast milk via the mother's diet.

I'm looking for the process as in what hormone does it bind to to allow this process in some women and not others?

Comment: Can you please show some of the research you have put into this question?